# Use of Swap space

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

I am trying to understand the Swap space and Virtual memory. These threads: [thread1](https://superuser.com/questions/42854/what-is-virtual-memory), [thread2](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-virtual-memory-and-swap-memory) say that Virtual memory is an abstraction and swap spaces merely are used in implementing virtual memory. Now, my questions are:

1) Are swap spaces special places in the hard disk that are used to temporarily store pages paged out from the RAM?

2) One more question is: Let's say I have a file F1 in hard disk and I'm currently operating on page P1 of file F1 (page P1 is in RAM) and I updated my page P1. Currently, page P1 in memory and page P1 in hard disk are divergent. Let's say the OS decided to page out P1 from memory. So, what has to happen is the page P1 has to move out of RAM and go somewhere in the hard disk. My understanding is that it either one of the following will happen:

a) has to go to the swap space in which case the page P1 in disk is still not updated yet (not yet flushed)

or

b) the page P1 gets flushed to disk in which case the file F1 in disk is up to date.

What will happen here, a or b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Are swap spaces special places in the hard disk that are used to
>   temporarily store pages paged out from the RAM?

Yes.  Depending on how the OS is configured, the swap space might be a separate partition, or perhaps just a special file in the filesystem.  In either case, it's like you say:  its purpose is to temporarily hold pages that have been swapped out of RAM.

> I'm currently operating on page P1 of file F1 (page P1 is in RAM) and
>   I updated my page P1

It's a little ambiguous what you mean by "operating on" here -- you might mean that you've used fopen() (or similar) to open a file handle and are using that file handle to read from and/or write to the contents of the file.  We'll call that scenario A.

Alternatively, you might have used mmap() (or something equivalent) to map the file's contents into virtual memory, so that you can access the file's contents directly via a pointer, as if it was a regular in-memory buffer.  We'll call that scenario B.

> Currently, page P1 in memory and page P1 in hard disk are divergent.
>   Let's say the OS decided to page out P1 from memory.

In scenario A (with fopen()), the pages of the file aren't themselves "in memory" in any relevant sense; rather, when the program calls fread() (or similar), the OS copies some bytes from the file into an in-memory buffer that the program passed to the fread() call.  There is indeed a copy of some data from the file in memory, and that data might get paged out to the swap file, but that data is not tied to the file itself (except in the sense that the program might be planning eventually to fwrite() it back into the file -- but the OS doesn't know that).  So in this scenario, the paged-out memory will go into the swap space, but that won't affect the on-disk file in any way.

In scenario B (with mmap()), the OS "knows" that the page in memory has a direct one-to-one mapping to the corresponding subset of the file, and in this case the OS may very well page the data out directly into the mmap'd file rather than going though the standard swap space and then to the file.  (An OS is certainly not *required* to be clever in that way, but I believe that most modern/popular OS's will do it the more efficient way, because it's more efficient and there's no reason not to)

Comment: I was referring to fopen followed by a fwrite onto page P1. So scenario A is what I was referring to. As a follow up, what is the main advantage of swap space? Let's say that page P1 of file F1 was brought into memory and I wrote some new data into P1. Now the page is divergent from the page in disk. Now, if OS pages out P1 into swap space it's essentially moving from RAM to disk which takes a lot of time. It can instead write that page to the actual page in disk and when the page is referenced again take it from the file directly instead of the swap space because both of them reside in disk

Comment: The main advantage of swap space is that if your computer runs out of RAM, it can continue operating.  (Without swap space enabled, RAM exhaustion means that something will simply fail; usually in that scenario the OS chooses a process to kill in order to free up some memory, but in some (mostly older) OSs the whole OS could crash)

Comment: If the computer runs out of RAM, it swaps out a page to swap space. This way it creates an illusion that there is more space in the RAM. Instead, why not push the page to its actual location in disk and take it back from there if and when needed? This will also guarantee the same illusion right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: When you call fwrite() on the data, the fwrite() call copies the specified bytes into the filesystem cache.  At that point the OS assumes responsibility for making sure that your update will get written to the file-on-disk, sooner or later (but likely not immediately).  Meanwhile, after the fwrite() call returns, the bytes in the application's buffer no longer have any particular relation to the file -- they are again just some bytes in RAM.  I suppose an OS could be smart, recognize the redundancy with the file contents, and optimize for that, but I doubt any OS's actually are that smart.

Comment: Actually, I thought of a reason why an OS (probably) couldn't make that optimization.  Say your scenario A occurs, and then before the page of memory gets swapped back in, some other program modifies the file-on-disk.  Then when your program's memory got swapped back in (from the file-on-disk), its in-application buffer would be "magically" different from what it was when the page was swapped out.... which would be an error.  So the OS would somehow have to detect and prevent that from happening.

Comment: Isn't this a concurrency issue? Concurrency is not provided by the OS for regular files right? So, a normal read and write of a file can go wrong in case something you said happens. Such problems should be avoided by the application programmer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112347/discussion-between-jeremy-friesner-and-harun-rashid).