# When memory returns to RAM after going to SWAP

Tags: linux, swap

In Red hat linux, if OS starts using the SWAP memory for some reason, when it will decide to use RAM again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of Swap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311714/use-of-swap-space)

Comment: The CPU can only use RAM. Swap space is used for temporary storage when everything doesn't fit in RAM. It has to be read back into RAM to use it.

Comment: Memory is never preemptively swapped back in. If memory is swapped out and remains unused, it will stay in swap forever.